# Set Max Approval use big number

Tags: 0x, bignumber

i am want create max approval fot approve token transaction on polygon exchange like this

```
const maxApproval = new BigNumber(2).pow(256).minus(1);
```

i see the documention in https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/advanced-topics/how-to-set-your-token-allowances#setting-allowances-on-etherscan

but i got error in run build like this

`invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value="115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935`

what the best max approval token allowance in polygon ?

0x.js: ^9.2.0,
typescript": 4.9.3

Comment: How are you using that value?

Answer (score 1):

in ethers you can use the built-in max numbers like:

```
ethers.constants.MaxUint256

ethers.constants.MaxInt256
```

Hope to helps!